# Canonical Q&A needed? function evaluation before plotting

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, site-organization

The need to move as much computation as possible outside of the `Plot` loop is one that comes up again and again, perhaps most recently in [Why is this 2D plot so slow?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/106141/why-is-this-2d-plot-so-slow/106142#106142)

I think we need a canonical Q&A for this problem that can serve as a master duplicate.  It will need to address all common aspects of this issue.

To begin with I request help collecting links for the existing Q&A's that share this solution.  From there we can identify all salient points and decide which Question, if any, is sufficiently clear and general enough to become canonical.

If you feel that this process should not take place vote down on this post.  Otherwise please help as you feel inclined.

Comment: Suppose none of questions located is in itself sufficiently clear and complete to serve as a canonical question? Would you then create a community wiki Franken-question along with a Franken-answer to serve as the desired canonical post?

Comment: @m_goldberg Possibly, yes.  Another possibility is to add it to the already long pitfalls post, but I think that makes duplicate redirects less useful as one would need to look a bit harder to figure out which part it is supposed to refer to.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Well, I certainly agree that adding to the pitfalls post should be avoided. It's a great post, but as you say, so long that it is hard to direct people to the specific topic that will help them most. Other than that, I should make it clear that I don't think a Franken-post would be a bad solution.